# How can I calculate where a table is cut?

Tags: html, printing

I've generated a simple HTML page with a big table with https://gist.github.com/MartinThoma/056183bc0862a787a8d4e8fe57e51f3f

Now I thought that the standard printing option would be 300dpi and this an A4 page has 2480 Pixels x 3508 Pixels ([source](http://www.a4papersize.org/a4-paper-size-in-pixels.php))

The Google Chrome PDF printing plugin cuts the page at / in column 7:

[image]

But when I calculate the width with

```
var width_total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    var theTh = $("#colTh" + i)
    var thWidth = 0;  // in pixel
    thWidth += theTh.width();
    thWidth += parseInt(theTh.css("padding-left"), 10) + parseInt(theTh.css("padding-right"), 10); //Total Padding Width
    thWidth += parseInt(theTh.css("margin-left"), 10) + parseInt(theTh.css("margin-right"), 10); //Total Margin Width
    thWidth += parseInt(theTh.css("borderLeftWidth"), 10) + parseInt(theTh.css("borderRightWidth"), 10); //Total Border Width

    width_total += thWidth;
    console.log("width " + i + ": " + width_total)
}
```

I have a width of `1200` at column 7.

**Where did I make a mistake in calculating the printable width?**

- Margins / borders / padding / width: I think this should be correct
- Page density in DPI: If it was something between 140 and 150 it could fit. Is there a way to find out what the browser is using / set a density?
- Something else?

Comment: `pdfinfo` tells me the generated PDF has `Page size:      595 x 842 pts (A4)`. That fits to A4 Dimensions @ 72 DPI. But then it should cut the page between 6 and 7 ...

Comment: Interesting. Even though I use `th, td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto; width: 150px;max-width: 150px;min-width:150px;}`, Firefox still fits all columns on one page while chrome breaks in / after column 7

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

1. The browser adjusts the table ("shrink to fit"). The user can disable this in the browsers print settings.
2. The default resultion is 96 DPI. 210mm is the width of an A4 page, 25.4mm/inch => 96 px/inch * (1/25.4) inch/mm * 210mm = 794px.